# The localization formula for orbifolds

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, equivariant-cohomology

The ABBV localization formula relates equivariant cohomology of a manifold to the equivariant cohomology of the fixed point set of the action. Wikipedia states the [ABBV Localization formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_formula_for_equivariant_cohomology) in the setting of orbifolds. I am looking for a reference of this formula in this setting and a proof of it.

I am aware that this formula is stated in [Meinrenken's paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870897917011). I am not an expert on orbifolds, and I find his discussion of this formula terse and there is no proof. Is there an alternate source of the localization formula for orbifolds that I am not aware of?

Comment: see https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/38409/36025851-MIT.pdf?sequence=2

Comment: See, Theorem 4.1 in http://www.mi.uni-koeln.de/~dgreb/localisation.pdf, I read this paper 4 years ago https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~michele.vergne/pageperso/transparents_conferences/circlepioline.pdf

Comment: In the Lie group theoretic sense, such formula are important, see slides 8, 9, and 10, http://fr.slideshare.net/HassanJolany/geometric-quantization-on-coadjoint-orbits . In fact you can find volume of coadjoint orbits by using such formula

Comment: It seems that this is in Duistermaat's "The Heat Kernel Lefschetz Fixed Point Formula for the Spin-c Dirac Operator", chapter 14. (To be precise, that's the K-theory version.)